# gcc switch -Wc++0x-compat is being used for C code

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm trying to use as much gcc warning switches as possible to ascertain whether they help make my code cleaner or even find problems.

I'm using these warning switches for C:

```
warnings_common = ['-Werror', '-Wfatal-errors', '-Wpedantic', '-pedantic', '-pedantic-errors', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Wchar-subscripts', '-Wcomment', '-Wno-coverage-mismatch', '-Wno-cpp', '-Wdouble-promotion', '-Wformat', '-Wnonnull', '-Winit-self', '-Wimplicit-int', '-Wimplicit-function-declaration', '-Wimplicit', '-Wignored-qualifiers', '-Wmain', '-Wmissing-braces', '-Wmissing-include-dirs', '-Wparentheses', '-Wsequence-point', '-Wno-return-local-addr', '-Wreturn-type', '-Wswitch', '-Wswitch-default', '-Wswitch-enum', '-Wsync-nand', '-Wtrigraphs', '-Wunused-but-set-parameter', '-Wunused-but-set-variable', '-Wunused-function', '-Wunused-label', '-Wunused-local-typedefs', '-Wunused-parameter', '-Wno-unused-result', '-Wunused-variable', '-Wunused-value', '-Wunused', '-Wuninitialized', '-Wmaybe-uninitialized', '-Wunknown-pragmas', '-Wno-pragmas', '-Wstrict-aliasing', '-Wstrict-overflow', '-Warray-bounds', '-Wno-div-by-zero', '-Wsystem-headers', '-Wtrampolines', '-Wfloat-equal', '-Wtraditional', '-Wtraditional-conversion', '-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '-Wundef', '-Wno-endif-labels', '-Wshadow', '-Wno-free-nonheap-object', '-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations', '-Wno-pedantic-ms-format', '-Wpointer-arith', '-Wtype-limits', '-Wbad-function-cast', '-Wc++-compat', '-Wc++11-compat', '-Wcast-qual', '-Wcast-align', '-Wwrite-strings', '-Wclobbered', '-Wconversion', '-Wempty-body', '-Wenum-compare', '-Wjump-misses-init', '-Wsign-compare', '-Wsign-conversion', '-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess', '-Waddress', '-Wlogical-op', '-Waggregate-return', '-Wno-aggressive-loop-optimizations', '-Wno-attributes', '-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined', '-Wstrict-prototypes', '-Wold-style-declaration', '-Wold-style-definition', '-Wmissing-parameter-type', '-Wmissing-prototypes', '-Wmissing-declarations', '-Wmissing-field-initializers', '-Wno-multichar', '-Wno-deprecated', '-Wno-deprecated-declarations', '-Wno-overflow', '-Woverride-init', '-Wpacked', '-Wpacked-bitfield-compat', '-Wpadded', '-Wredundant-decls', '-Wnested-externs', '-Winline', '-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast', '-Wno-pointer-to-int-cast', '-Winvalid-pch', '-Wlong-long', '-Wvariadic-macros', '-Wvarargs', '-Wvector-operation-performance', '-Wvla', '-Wvolatile-register-var', '-Wdisabled-optimization', '-Wpointer-sign', '-Wstack-protector', '-Woverlength-strings', '-Wunsuffixed-float-constants']
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
cc1: error: command line option '-Wc++0x-compat' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]
```

which seems strange since I'm compiling a C file:

```
int main(void);

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

Which switch from the above is calling '-Wc++0x-compat' and why?

Comment: `-Wall` triggers this, I don't know if other flags do, but `Wall` is for sure. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Try taking out `'-Wc++11-compat'`.  `c++0x` is an old name for `c++11`

Comment: woolstar gave the right answer, but you know, you could have tried removing flags until the error disappeared...

Comment: OK, I was looking at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html, which does not mention '-Wc++0x-compat'. Also the man page for gcc does not mention this switch. I'm using version 4.8.1.

Comment: @user2242584 I repeat woolstar's advice: **remove `-Wc++11-compat` from your list.**

Comment: @woolstar From the man page '-Wc++11-compat' is listed in the common warning options (so it should be supported for C), but in its description it says "for C++ and Objective-C++ only".

Comment: @MarcGlisse I did that but only for those options for whose the compiler stated "is valid for --- but not for C".

Comment: Removing '-Wc++11-compat' worked. I don't think '-Wall' triggers this, at least in version 4.8.1, since it wouldn't make sense to trigger non-C switches. Probably there is a slight bug in gcc: instead of complaining about the switch given in the command line it was complaining about a switch triggered by a switch in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

With `gcc` ( and other compilers), some flags are just a placeholder for a larger set of flags, like `-Wall`, you can read about the flags in the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

If you like to disable a particular flag use the `-Wno` prefix, like `-Wno-c++0x-compat` if you want to disable just this one.

Comment: I tried that, but "cc1: error: command line option '-Wno-c++0x-compat' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]"